# Deleting folder completely, but it comes back

Tags: command-line, delete, rm

I have this folder in Ubuntu 18.04 that I completely removed.

```
sudo rm -rf folder_name
```

It has been deleted, but after a while, the folder comes back, but only with the *.cache* directory in the folder. It takes about 1 minute until the folder comes back with only the *.cache* folder in the folder that I want to delete.

I change the permission of the both the *.cache* folder and the folder itself, deleted them, but it keeps coming back. I also deleted everything piece by piece.

There is also in the *.cache* folder a *pgdata* folder.

Thanks,

[edit]
Yeah so I was able to finally delete it. As someone pointed out, a process was creating that folder in the background. It was a docker container.

Comment: There must be a process creating the folder. Where is it located?

Comment: It seems to be a PostgreSQL folder

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the problem! It was a docker container (running postgresql) that was still running in the background. I stop and deleted the container and was able to delete the folder! Thanks!

Comment: Without specifying the `folder_name` this isn't a good question. However, more generically if you use `lsof | grep "folder_name"` (with the internal double quotes) then `lsof` will give you a list of the processes that have a folder open. `lsof | grep "cache"` will show you a ton of processes with caches; less blunt is `lsof +c0 +d "/home/$USER/.cache"` which shows all processes with files open from the ~/.cache directory.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem using docker and a postgres container (as @schrodigerscatcuriosity mentioned [what a name btw])

The steps I followed:

1. `doker ps`
2. `docker stop <<container_name>>`
3. `sudo chmod 777 -R <<folder_to_delete>>`
4. `rm -rf <<folder_to_delete>>`

EDIT: Docker was still creating the <<folder_to_delete>> when I ran it. So, I had to remove the docker images/containers/volumes.

(keep in mind that you'll remove all the docker info so you'll have to re-install them again). [Additional info](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

- `docker system prune -a --volumes`

I use PyCharm as IDE. I had to remove the <<folder_to_delete>> from recent projects as well.

[image]